# Does a flight dispatcher need to update the flight plan during GTB and ATB?

Tags: flight-planning, dispatch

Does a flight dispatcher need to recalculate and resubmit the flight plan to the pilot during ground turn back (GTB) and air turn back (ATB) scenarios?

Comment: Hello Raj, welcome to Aviation.SE! Please expand the acronyms to full words when you use the for the first time in your text. Also, we prefer the title to be in question form.

Comment: Does GTB and ATB mean gate turn back and air turn back?

Comment: Yes. Ground Turn Back and Air Turn back ..

Comment: Are you talking about the operative flight plan (used in the cockpit) or the ATC flightplan?

Comment: Operative flight plan to the pilots in the cockpit.